# Blackjack program in python

Tags: python, playing-cards

I just started learning to program last week and I'm having trouble writing a blackjack program. I can generate a deck list but I can't seem to think of a way to assign the cards values according to the rules of blackjack. Like face cards are equal to 10, ace can be 1 or 1,1 and the rest are equal to their face value. I know my code is probably a mess to you guys, but I would rather continue with it and make mistakes and learn, rather than copy and pastes a pros work. So could you give me some tips to assign the cards values, thanks.

Here is what I have so far

```
import random
import time

deck = []
hand = []
dealer_hand = []
def deck_shuffle():
    for suit in ["Clubs", "Dimonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]:
        for face in ["Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]:
            deck.append([face, suit])
        for num in range(2, 11):
            deck.append([num, suit])
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck



def deal_cards():
    for x in range(0,2):
        deal_card = deck.pop(0)
        hand.append(deal_card)
        deal_card = deck.pop(0)
        dealer_hand.append(deal_card)



deck_shuffle()
deal_cards()
print (deck)



print("Dealers hand is", dealer_hand)
print("Your hand is", hand)
```

Comment: Well, my first tip would be to use punctuation. (And spend less time repeating that you're a newbie. If just clutters the question, and if it has deficiencies they'll be pointed out for you to fix regardless.)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the best way to assign values to the cards without changing everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dict` here:

Example:

```
>>> card_vals = {"Jack" : 5, "Queen": 15, "King": 20, "Ace":10}
>>> card_vals.update({ x:x for x in range(2,11)})
>>> card_vals["Jack"]
5
>>> card_vals["Jack"]
5
>>> card_vals[2]
2
>>> card_vals[5]
5
```

Comment: perfect and would that work for the number cards as in card_vals = {"2" : 2}

Comment: @Mark you can similarly store numbers as well.

Comment: will that work in according with my method for assigning suits?

Comment: @Mark only change that part where you need a particular card's value(for doing some calculation).

Comment: yep that works very well thank you

Comment: Will work, but be deadly slow. The real answer is to stop using strings. Strings are for people; computers use numbers. Check out [Representing playing cards in software](http://etceterology.com/blog/2013/5/23/representing-playing-cards-in-software)

Comment: Thanks  for the link Lee, I see what you mean. If my lists were bigger it would run terribly slow,  and i ended up reading nearly everything else on that blog very interesting reading haha

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
class Card:
     def __init__(self,suit,value):
         self.suit = suit
         self.value = value
     def __str__(self):
         return "A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K".split(",")[self.value]+" of "+["Clubs", "Dimonds", "Hearts", "Spades"][self.suit]
     def getValue(self):
          if 0 <self.value < 10: return self.value + 1
          if self.value == 0: return 11
          return 10

class Deck:
      def __init__(self):
          self.cards = [Card(i,j) for i in range(4) for j in range(13)]
          self.cards.shuffle()

d = Deck()
print d.cards[0]
print d.cards[0].getValue()
```

Comment: Yeah i knew i would get answers with classes and other things by far the more efficient code but i have no experience with classes yet and i'm trying to stick to what i know instead of confusing myself thank you for your answer all the same